# Comparing two columns and if condition is met add '1' to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I cannot figure out how to compare two columns and if one columns is greater than or equal to another number input '1' to a new column. If the condition is not met I would like python to do nothing.

The data set for testing is here:

```
data = [[12,10],[15,10],[8,5],[4,5],[15,'NA'],[5,'NA'],[10,10], [9,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'Benchmark'])

   Score Benchmark
0     12        10
1     15        10
2      8         5
3      4         5
4     15        NA
5      5        NA
6     10        10
7      9        10
```

The desired output is:

```
desired_output_data = [[12,10, 1],[15,10,1],[8,5,1],[4,5],[15,'NA'],[5,'NA'],[10,10,1], [9,10]]
desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame(desired_output_data, columns = ['Score', 'Benchmark', 'MetBench'])

   Score Benchmark  MetBench
0     12        10       1.0
1     15        10       1.0
2      8         5       1.0
3      4         5       NaN
4     15        NA       NaN
5      5        NA       NaN
6     10        10       1.0
7      9        10       NaN
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
if df['Score'] >= df['Benchmark']:
    df['MetBench'] = 1
```

I am new to programming in general so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Use: `df['MetBench'] = np.where(df['Score'] >= df['Benchmark'], 1, np.NaN)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use`ge` and `map`

```
df.Score.ge(df.Benchmark).map({True: 1, False:np.nan})
```

or use the mapping from `False` to `np.nan` implicitly, since pandas uses the `dict.get` method to apply the mapping, and `None` is the default value (thanks `@piRSquared`)

```
df.Score.ge(df.Benchmark).map({True: 1})
```

Or simply `series.where`

```
df.Score.ge(df.Benchmark).where(lambda s: s)
```

Both outputs

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    1.0
7    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Make sure to do

```
df['Benchmark'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Benchmark'], errors='coerce')
```

first, since you have `'NA'` as a string, but you need the numeric value `np.nan` to be able to compare it with other numbers

Comment: `df.Score.ge(df.Benchmark).map({True: 1})`  The way pandas uses map is that it converts a dictionary to it's callable `dict.get` which returns `None` when a key doesn't exist.

Comment: @piRSquared Living and learning ;} Will add